# Ajax method to a webmethod in asmx is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a strange problem with the below AJAX jQuery method to call a webmethod in an asmx service. It's not firing when I try to call it, but the moment I uncomment any of the alert in code to debug, it works all of sudden.

It confuses me, what would be the problem? Am I missing something here..

Code:

```
var endXsession = function() {

  var fwdURL = "";
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Session.asmx/RemoveSession",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msge) {
      //alert(msge.d);
      fwdURL = msge.d;
    },
    error: function(response) {
      //alert(response.responseText);
      fwdURL = response.responseText;
    }

  });
  //alert(fwdURL);
  return fwdURL;
};
```

Comment: Since  the ajax call you are making is async, you do know that your fwdURL will always be empty when you return it, no? I don't see a reason why your function would no longer work when you would uncomment the alerts. If you want to debug in javascript, add the `debugger;` statement and use the developer tools ;)

Comment: thanks @Icepickle !!...Yep the call was asynchronous that's the reason it worked when put an alert to stop the execution momentarily..I just added an attribute async:false and it got resolved...Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

response.responseText is undefined ... it's response.statusText ..

```
function endXsession() {
var fwdURL = "";

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "Session.asmx/RemoveSession",
              data: "{}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (msge) {
                  // alert(msge.d);
                  fwdURL = msge.d;                         
              }
              ,
              error: function (response) {
                  // alert(response.statusText);
                  fwdURL = response.statusText;
              }

          });
          // alert(fwdURL);
          return fwdURL;
      }   
    console.log(endXsession());
```